# SSIS Unexpected Termination - Excel Import - Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0

Tags: excel, ssis

When I launch my job from the server it reports a status of Unexpected Termination :

[image]

The package import a file Excel ( about 3000 lines) , its ok in visual studio 2019

From the server it writes a few lines (about 600 lines) in the table then ends with this error

Expression connection string :

> Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source=N:\BI_Files\toto.xlsx;Extended Properties="EXCEL 12.0 XML;HDR=YES";

accessdatabaseengine_X64.exe is well installed

The job is run in 64 bit mode, otherwise I have the message the 32 bit driver is not installed if I test the job in 32 bit.

Comment: Good job on your first question. Relevant information and it shows that you've tried some of the basic items (64 vs 32 bit mode).

Comment: If you were getting no data imported, then I would assume it's the connection string property referencing a (likely) mapped N drive. A UNC path (\\server\share\BI_Files) is usually easier as it doesn't require desktop interactivity with service accounts. But that's troubleshooting for a different problem... I know you say the same file works in VS, but is there anything "weird" in the file, like an image? I seem to recall running into errors loading a worksheet that had the provider's logo in it.